# How to enable delete functionality in lotus notes searchview form?

Tags: lotus-domino, lotusscript

I hope you can help me on this, We've got a project in our team and the client needs to have a search functionality in a view. The application is web based by the way. By default we used the default search functionality of notes we used the `@URLOpen("/" + @WebDbName + "/" + @ViewTitle + "/$SearchForm?SearchView")` function to call the default Search for domino. As expected it was working, user can search and search results appear. The only problem is, the user wants to enable a delete functionality right there in the search. I do know how to delete documents in a view the works in the web, but this one eludes me since the  `$SearchForm?SearchView` form, or whatever it is, is not common knowledge to me. I don't know where to find them. As for my research , I didn't get any clear results about my query so I ended up here. I really hope you guys can help. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Get document's UniqueID you want to delete and call url

```
 http://server/db.nsf/uniquedocid?DeleteDocument
```

Comment: Sorry but you lost me there friend. The user needs to have a check box, much like the functionality in a native notes application. Say, for example, I search AAA in the search bar and search results appear, Check box should be displayed in the left side of the record. Much like the native notes view client. So this user will check the box of the document he wants to delete and hit delete.

Comment: You have to customize search form and add delete functionality with select boxes and a button http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_CUSTOMIZING_SEARCH_FORMS_7304.html

Comment: Thank you, I will definitely check it.